# Blocking part of a website

Tags: dns, osx-leopard, google-reader

I am trying to block Google Reader:

reader.google.com

**www.google.com/reader**

**The hard part is blocking the reader directory**

I blocked reader.google.com by changing my /etc/hosts file (this is for a Mac)

Is there any way to block www.google.com/reader without buying software?
Note this is for Safari so Greasemonkey won't work, and Leopard's Parental Controls throttle the CPU when they are turned on.

Also I've tried OpenDNS, which is awesome, but doesn't work for this...

Any thoughts?

**Update:** This is for a laptop that travels a lot. So a router or a home proxy server won't work. Firefox would work, but I don't think I can uninstall Safari from a mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Privoxy](http://www.privoxy.org/) to filter about anything.

Comment: Thanks! I had been using OpenDNS, but I couldn't control at the directory level.

Answer (score 1):

Set up a proxy server and block it via that.

-Adam

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with a proxy (for example [Proxomitron](http://proxomitron.info/index.html)).

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use a free service like www.opendns.com as your dns servers, they allow you to block specific domains or turn on filtering etc.

Answer (score 0):

What about at the router level?  My router as an URL blocker built in.

Comment: No, this is for a laptop that moves around a lot. It never uses the same router.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can find some sort of http proxy you could install to filter this content and use that when browsing. On Firefox you could easily define a rule for Adblock Plus.

Answer (score 0):

I did exactly what you're looking for using [Safari AdBlock](http://safariadblock.sourceforge.net/). Just define a few rules in Safari->Preferences->AdBlock and you should be good to go!